# Derive from std:string to add typedefs and enums

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, stdstring

For UDP packages exchanged between client and server I would like to support two kinds of string fields:

- null-terminated c-string named `cstring`
- string with preceeding `uint8_t` size-field named `vstring`

To self-document the layout of our packages I would like to use simple struct declarations:

```
struct ABC {
  vstring a;
  cstring b;
}
```

And call overloaded functions `get(char*, vstring& v)` and `get(char*, cstring&)` inside de/serialization function like this:

```
void deserialize(const char* bytes, ABC& msg) {
  get(msg.a);
  get(msg.b);
}

void serialize(char* bytes, const ABC& msg) {
  put(msg.a);
  put(msg.b);
}
```

However, for the user `vstring` and `cstring` should ideally behave just like normal `std::string`.

My first idea was to simply make `std::string` a public base of `vstring` and `cstring` such that the two classes can be disriminated during overload-resolution but behave the same for the user. But since deriving from `std::string` is discouraged, I am unsure what to do.

Comment: I don't quite understand why do you need new types? Why is `string` bad? It exposes `const char*` and has `size()` method, so it seems like you are duplicating functionality. Could you clarify this? It kinda looks like XY question.

Comment: Deals is you'll have to serialize `vstring` and `cstring` because sending objects through networks that way won't always work.

Comment: Technically, I only need `vstring` and `cstring` to be distinct types during my `serialize()` and `deserialize()` functions. For the user of `struct ABC` it does not matter.

Comment: Why not to use composition?

Answer (score 4):

The danger of deriving from `std::string` is that the destructor is not virtual, so someone might do this:

```
std::string* p = new vstring;
delete p;
```

You'd have undefined behaviour.  If you think that code like that has no chance of being written in your environment/system, knock yourself out and derive from `std::string`.

Guidelines:

- If the `vstring` and `cstring` classes are only being used in a very limited, controlled environment - preferably by one or a small number of developers with whom you can communicated the expected - and monitor the actual - usage, or where it's clear that dynamic allocation and polymorphism won't be abused to handle them, all's good.
- At the other extreme - if they're in your interfaces to unspecified amounts of uncontrolled code, where it's not even practical to inform all the would-be client developers of the issue - that's not good, and a scenario in which you should prefer not to derive from types without virtual destructors.

---

That said, do you really need to encode the serialisation style in the type?  They have to write serialisation and deserialisation routines anyway, which list the fields to be serialised, and they could specify the format (NUL-terminated vs. length-prefixed or whatever else) in there too.

Comment: So, if I were to add a custom destructor to `struct vstring` that explicitly calls the base class destructor I am safe?

Comment: @Arne No - it's not so easy.  Any destructor - custom or compiler-provided - for `vstring` ***won't be called*** if the destructor for the base class is directly invoked (e.g. using `delete p;` as in my example code). C++ provides virtual dispatch to let base classes support customisation of the destruction in that situation, but once the base class is written you can't retrospectively make a function virtual.  Note that if the `vstring` is a member of `ABC`, an object on the stack etc. - the need to call the `vstring` destructor is known at compile time: no problem.

Comment: @Arne *I was 4s late to Tony* . I'll just add that generally idiomatically in c++ any class that is expected to be derived from *should* define a virtual destructor. Even an empty one, just as a precaution for this. Otherwise, you couldn't safely mix objects of `Base` and `Derived` in standard containers eventhough you can always cast `Derived` to `Base`, if `Derived` has destructors, they wouldn't be called when the container goes out of scope.

Comment: I'll add to luk'32 comment that there are good *practical* reasons that C++ didn't make virtual destructors the default, despite it being appealing from an OO correctness perspective: virtual dispatch has a performance overhead, prevents bitwise copying/moving, requires a (n extra) pointer per object, may prevent or restrict placement of objects in shared memory or handling of existing data at known addresses using pointers to class objects etc.. So, C++ lets programmers choose.

Answer (score 2):

Ideologically, the way of serialization shouldn't affect the type of data, so I'd better do something like this:

```
void serializeNullTerminated(char* bytes, const std::string& msg);
void deserializeNullTerminated(const char* bytes, std::string& msg);

void serializeWithSize(char* bytes, const std::string& msg);
void deserializeWithSize(const char* bytes, std::string& msg);
```

Or pass an additional parameter to the functions:

```
void serialize(SerializationType st, char* bytes, const std::string& msg);
void deserialize(SerializationType st, const char* bytes, std::string& msg);
```

Or you can make them template:

```
template<SerializationType st>
void serialize(char* bytes, const std::string& msg);
template<SerializationType st>
void deserialize(const char* bytes, std::string& msg);
```

The point is, the user won't have to deal with different types of strings, in their code, they only have to choose the way of serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decouple the computation from the messages. So in your program you work with `std::string`, and when you need to send/receive strings you pass messages conform with your protocol.

So the only public interfaces of your library/application/whatever should be something like:

```
int send_message(std::string const &s, int mode, ... destination ... etc);
int receive_message(std::string &s, int mode, ... source ... etc);
```

(with possible overloads of `char *c` (null-terminated) for `s`).

with mode being a flag `MODE_CSTRING` or `MODE_VSTRING`.

Internally you send/receive:

- a vector of null-terminated characters or
- the size and then the vector of characters.

You don't even need to create classes for `cstring` and `vstring`.